# ¿Cómo hago una recursividad para ver si un número N esta ausente en un número K?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
program project1;
{$codepage utf8}

FUNCTION Digito_Aus(nro,nro2:integer):boolean;
begin
  IF (nro div 10)=0 then
    Digito_Aus:=nro <> nro2
  else digito_aus:=false;
end;
var S,k:integer;
Begin
  Writeln('Ingrese un numero: ');readln(S,k);
  write(digito_aus(s,k));
  readln
end.
```

**Este es el planteo que tengo de momento que es el caso base ahora con un solo digito lo que me esta costando realizar es el caso general se que puedo hacer con div y mod pero todavía no logro como implementarlo.
Ejemplo: (5,1313) retornara a true, 1(1332) retornara a false**

Comment: UY!!! si todavía existe Pascal, que recuerdos. ¿Que quieres decir exactamente con que un número esté contenido en otro? ¿El 3 está contenido en 5?

Comment: Creo que vendría bien un ejemplo de lo que quieres conseguir, ya que actualmente publicas código y solo dices que no te funciona, pero sin saber exactamente lo que quieres, ¿cómo decir qué es lo que le está faltando?

Comment: @Juan claro que existe, nunca ha dejado de hacerlo. :)

Comment: @jachguate Oh perdón pensé que lo había publicado, por ejemplo si ingreso n=5 y k=5 entonces es false porque el numero si esta presente pero si n=5 y k=1 es true porque el 5 esta ausente. Eso seria mi caso base cuando tengo un solo digito ahora lo que me dificulta difícil es el caso general cuando Tenes mas de un dígito.

Answer (score 0):

La lógica, para saber si un dígito está ausente de un número, es ir recorriendo el número, dígito por dígito y detenerse al comprobar que el dígito es igual al que estamos buscando.

Valiéndonos de las operaciones `mod 10` y `div 10`, podemos ir tomando el último dígito del número para compararlo. Usamos 10, porque es la base del sistema decimal.

Uniendo lo dicho, podemos crear una función que nos diga si un dígito está ausente de un número o no. No he conservado ni el nombre de la función ni de los parámetros que propones en el ejemplo, pues las buenas prácticas nos orientan al uso de nombres  significativos, que hacen los programas más fáciles de leer y entender.

```
program so464236;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function EstaAusenteDigito(Digito, Numero: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  Digito := Digito mod 10;  //nos aseguramos que es un solo dígito.
  while (Result) and (Numero > 0) do
  begin
    Result := Numero mod 10 <> Digito;
    Numero := Numero div 10;
  end;
end;

Begin
  Writeln('5, 1313 = ', EstaAusenteDigito(5, 1313));
  Writeln('1, 1332 = ', EstaAusenteDigito(1, 1332));
  Readln;
end.
```

Como puedes leer en el código, inicio la función asumiendo que el dígito está ausente, de esta manera si llega a recorrer todos los dígitos del número, saldrá con este resultado.

Luego, me aseguro de tener un solo dígito para realizar la comparación, por lo que tomo solo el último dígito del parámetro, en esta asignación: `Digito := Digito mod 10;`

Luego, con un ciclo `while` que se repetirá mientras no se haya encontrado un dígito y mientras aún le queden dígitos al número.

En cada iteración, primero, comparo el último dígito del número con el almacenado en el parámetro `Digito` y asigno el resultado de esa comparación al resultado de la función, auto-variable `Result`. Si el dígito es igual, al volverse `False` esta variable, terminará el ciclo y la función devolverá el valor `False`.

Luego *elimino* el último dígito del número dividiéndolo entre 10. Así, si comienzo con el número `1234`, me iré quedando con `123` luego `12`, luego `1` y finalmente `0`. Al llegar a este momento sin encontrar una coincidencia, se detendría el ciclo y saldría de la función con el valor `True`, que no ha cambiado a lo largo de la ejecución.

La salida obtenida con las llamadas de ejemplo es:

```
5, 1313 = TRUE
1, 1332 = FALSE
```

El programa de ejemplo está hecho y probado en Delphi, pero debiera compilar sin problemas en FreePascal.